# Is there a way to set a Web References URL in an Environment Variable instead of in the web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, api, web-config, environment-variables

I'd like to pull the Web References URL configuration out of my web.config so that we don't have to maintain separate config files for each environment.

The path we decided on was to store variables as Environment variables. Is there a way for me to point my Web Reference to use the URL variable that I set up instead of the web.config? I haven't been able to find anything yet...

Thanks!

Note, This is what I'm talking about when I say "Environment Variables":
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? Its just a `string`. Use [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx). You should set it at the system level so that its easier to configure. Make sure you provide a fall back and appropriate error handling.

Comment: when you new up the client, you can specify the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can access environment variables like so in c#:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NameOfVariable")
```